# Not able to set Url property at runtime in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a `webbrowser` control in my Winform application.

Below regions belong to division of code sample.

**Region 1**
The current url page loaded is "http://MyWebsite.com". I am clicking a link (say "About Us") in the web page using code. This click will take me to new url page ("http://MyWebsite.com/About_Us"). In Navigating event I am recording this new url.

**Region 2**
Now I want to get all elements of this new url and click on a new link. But not sure how to do it. In Region 2 I am also assigning the new url to webbrowser object. But nothing reflects in the instance. `webbrowser.url` still contains the previous url path.

I have following code for button click:

```
    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Region 1---------------------------------------------
        HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.InnerText != null && link.InnerText.Equals("Click to view magic"))
            {
                link.InvokeMember("Click");
                break;
            }
        }
        // EndRegion---------------------------------------------


        // Region 2---------------------------------------------
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(_url.AbsoluteUri, UriKind.Absolute);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(_url); //New Edit

        links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if ((link.GetAttribute("Name") == "BooHoo"))
            {
                link.InvokeMember("Click");
                break;
            }
        }
        // EndRegion---------------------------------------------
    }

    private void WebBrowser1Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        _url = e.Url;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to do this. The question may not be very clear. Please let me know if you need any further details. Thanks.

Comment: isn't there a Navigate method on the WebBrowswer object?  I think I remember having this problem and finding a method on the class to do the job I wanted of changing the URL.

Comment: I edited Region 2. Did you mean the same thing? If yes, its still not working.

Comment: perhaps I've set up the event differently than you, but I get Navigate in Region 2 to work.

Comment: can you post your code as an answer and let me know how you have actually setup the things for my better understandings....

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Url = _url;
            webBrowser1.Navigated += webBrowser1_Navigated;
        }

        void Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
            Button1Click();
        }

        void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            _url = e.Url;
            webBrowser1.Document.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_Click);
        }

Comment: essentially, I tied into the document click and the navigated events, since I wasn't sure where your method was being attached.  The reason I attach the event this way is that each navigation event loads a new Document, requiring new events to be tied to it.  Let me know if this helps or if you're looking for something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was tricky a bit or else I am careless. I was watching the property values in debug mode. Later I noticed that, after pressing `F5` in Visual Studio (continue debugging) and all the methods are run, `webbrowser` shows the changed values.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so you got the Click event before the Navigated event?  events are one of the biggest challenges to C# programming and have been the source of many a false negative and false positive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe Navigated event as WebBrowser works asynchronously.

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            --Do Something Here....
        }